# How to add conditionals to an await fetch request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I'm working with an API in Next.js and I'm trying to make a back/next button functional.
With my code though, I'm getting a "res is not defined".
How do I properly use conditionals with an await fetch request?

```
const Page = () => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const fetchContent = async (button) => {
    if (button === "back" && page > 1) {
      const res = await fetch(
        `http://api-page.com/content/pagination[page]=${page}`
      );
      setPage(page - 1);
    } else if (button === "next") {
      const res = await fetch(
        `http://api-page.com/content/pagination[page]=${page}`
      );
      setPage(page + 1);
    } else {
      const res = await fetch(
        `http://api-page.com/content/pagination[page]=${page}`
      );
    }
    const data = await res.json();
    setData(data.data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchContent();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          fetchContent("back");
        }}
      >
        Prev page
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          fetchContent("next");
        }}
      >
        Next page
      </button>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but all your conditional branches do exactly the same ``const res = await fetch(`http://api-page.com/content/pagination[page]=${page}`);``. Is that actually what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Your conditionals look fine. The problem is `const` (and `let`) being block-scoped: they disappear as soon as the block they were defined in ends. Here is your situation, simplified:

```js
{
  const a = 1;
  console.log("inside a block", a);   // 1
}
console.log("outside a block", a);    // ReferenceError
```

The solution: make `res` not a constant, and declare it at the scope you will use it:

```js
let a;
{
  a = 1;
  console.log("inside a block", a);   // 1
}
console.log("outside a block", a);    // 1
```